# Trying to create a calculate MM to CBM

Tags: java, android-studio

I tried to create an App with three number text fields for size calculation in MM, where the result would give the volume of an item. Hence within the MainActivity.java I have tried to convert the MM into Meters and then calculate Meters into CBM (Volume). It is not working as it has a class error and one string doesnt work. Can you help me correct my mistake as this is my first try on making something myself.

```
public class onCreate(View view) {

    EditText textL = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.textL);
    EditText textB = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.textB);
    EditText textH = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.textH);

    Button click = (Button) findViewById(R.id.calculateButton);

    double aL = double.parseDouble(textL.getText().toString());
    double aB = double.parseDouble(textB.getText().toString());
    double aH = double.parseDouble(textH.getText().toString());

    double alAmount = aL * 0.001;
    double abAmount = aB * 0.001;
    double ahAmount = aH * 0.001;

    double cbmAmount = (alAmount*abAmount)*ahAmount;

    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Package CBM: " + cbmAmount, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();


}
```

Comment: Which string does not work? Which error exactly are you getting?

Comment: what is the error you are getting?

Comment: What do you insert into the `EditText`'s? It has to be convertable to a double. Did you use a comma instead of dot? Try debugging it and you will find the problem easily yourself. 
Additionally, you should use `Double.parseDouble` (capitalized). FInally, wrap `try ... catch` around each conversion, that way you ensure the conversions went correctly.